# prevent checkbox label from wrapping to opposite side of page

Tags: html, css, checkbox, label

As you can see in the image below then when the browser window is resized the checkbox labels can wrap to the opposite side of their ascociated checkboxes.
[image]

In the image above the label for checkbox 12 has wrapped and is at the opposite side of the screen. How can I make it so that each label stays with its checkbox?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Put the checkboxes in the label tags and give the label `display: inline-block`. Texts can be of any size, the "inline-block" keeps the text and checkbox together.

Demo (Resize your browser so 14 goes to the next line): http://jsfiddle.net/csYPu/

HTML:

```
<label><input type="checkbox">1</label>
<label><input type="checkbox">2</label>
<label><input type="checkbox">3</label>
```

CSS:

```
label {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would group the label and the checkbox in an element (`li`, `div`) and float them left.

Example:

**css**

```
ul {
  overflow: hidden;
}
li {
  float: left;
}
```

**html**

```
<ul>
  <li><input type="checkbox" name="box1" id="box1" value="1"><label for="box1">1</label></li>
  ...
  <li><input type="checkbox" name="box13" id="box13" value="1"><label for="box13">13</label></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: What about the different sizes of labels because the labels increment from 1 to 3 digits? wouldn't I have to specify a width?

Comment: @inquisitive_web_developer No, as long as you float the containing element - like the `li` in my example - they stay together until the page gets too small to accommodate the individual box and label on one line.

Comment: Okay, thanks @jeroen your example works, but I do like the method that @Bazzz provided as it is much simpler.